# Bootstrap v4 .modal("show") slow execution

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I've noticed that bootstrap's modals take time to show as the page's content becomes more significant.

It takes less than 100ms to show when the page is empty, but takes proportionally more time as the amount of content in the page becomes more significant.

I do not understand this correlation. Can anybody explain this behavior and suggest a workaround to make the modals appearance faster independently of the page's size ?

**EDIT**: You can reproduce the behavior by going *i.e* [here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal) and execute the command

`console.time("modalTime"); $("#exampleModal").modal("show"); console.timeEnd("modalTime");`

in console, to see how much time it takes. Then add more content to the page by manipulating the DOM and re-execute the command.

**My results**: `modalTime : 70 ms` on the original page. `modalTime : 1208 ms` after making the content of the page 10x larger.

Comment: When do you show the modal? On a click event? On page load?

Comment: Upon a click event.

Comment: maybe too much events on site, like `.on('resize')` which is very "unhealthly". Do you use jquery ?

Comment: I do use jQuery, but there aren't much events on the page.

Comment: You can reproduce the behavior by going to *i.e* https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ and execute the command ``console.time("modalTime"); $("#exampleModal").modal("show"); console.timeEnd("modalTime");`` in console, to see how much time it takes. Then add more content to the page by manipulating the DOM and re-execute the command.

Comment: modalTime: 13 ms debugger eval code:1:64

Comment: It takes 70ms on my side, have you tried adding more content (a lot) to the DOM ?

Comment: Could you prepare 2 Plunker examples for this? One with much content - one with little?

Comment: Ok, I am able tro reproduce a delay if I add 50.000 lines of text to the document: https://plnkr.co/edit/hvRAn3wg91GBCPxK2gwb?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I am able to reproduce a delay if I add 50.000 lines of text to the document: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/hvRAn3wg91GBCPxK2gwb?p=preview

The problem with a huge DOM like this is, that any manipulation will take long. 
It might be a problem of jQuery, but I doubt.

To prove that the delay has nothing to do with the Modal, I am painting the button to red when clicking it - even this simple action takes as long as opening the modal window.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    $( "#content" ).append( "This is just some test. This is just some test. This is just some test. This is just some test. This is just some test. This is just some test. This is just some test. This is just some test. This is just some test. <br/>" );
  }

  $("#btnToggleMoadal").click(function(e) {
    $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
    $(this).css({backgroundColor:"red"});
  });
});
```

**Edit:** I have also tested jQuery's onClick vs onClick out of the DOM - but there is no difference. https://plnkr.co/edit/483Sk2FGXk9lT8dLZIdo?p=info

**Edit:** I have to correct my answer. It's definitely the Bootstrap Modal which causes the performance issue. I think the problem is somewhere around _adjustDialog() in modal.js.

I recommend to open an issue at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues and show the Plunker example.

Comment: I don't think your argument is valid; if you delete the line ``$("#exampleModal").modal("show");`` then the button's color changes instantaneously.

Comment: Also, in order for the delay to become troublesome, one does not necessarily need 50.000 lines of text. In this case I understand it's done to explicit the delay, but in my app, the modal takes 1000ms to show with a list of only 100 items containing some links and little text.

Comment: @Guru - this is a valid point - I did not try to remove the .modal() function. I will continue to test this.